# Not able to display map of an object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to display some field of a object

```
private Integer id;
private String enumName;
private Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
...
```

In my controller I have

```
List<EnumTypesDto> enumTypes = enumTypesService.getAllEnumTypes();
model.addAttribute("enumTypes", enumTypes);
```

In my template I have

```
<p th:each="entry: ${enumTypes.fields}">
    <span th:text="'Key: ' + ${entry.key} + ', Value: ' + ${entry.value}"></span>
</p>
```

I get this error

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'fields' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your template. `enumTypes` is a list of `EnumTypesDto` objects, not a map `fields` you have defined inside `EnumTypesDto` class. I assume you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
<div th:each="type: ${enumTypes}">
    <h2 th:text="${type.enumName}">

    <p th:each="entry: ${type.fields}">
        <span th:text="'Key: ' + ${entry.key} + ', Value: ' + ${entry.value}"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

In above example we firstly iterate over all `EnumTypesDto` objects and for each object we iterate over `fields` map to display its keys and values. I hope it helps.